# Converting SED to Replace containing Regex and Dates

Tags: powershell, curl, sed, replace

Been slamming my head against the wall on this one but essentially I had a curl command and it contained a replace (sed) command and I would like to convert this to the powershell equivalent of using replace and I feel like my order of quotes/escaping text isn't quite right.

My output would be like so: `"cattle.io/timestamp":"2022-02-22T11:11:00Z"`

And the only part i would like to change is the date/time stamp so that it updates to the current datetime.

The following works in curl:  `sed "s/\"cattle\.io\/timestamp\"\:\"[0-9T:Z-]*\"/\"cattle\.io\/timestamp\":\"(date -u +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")"/g"`

I thought it would be something like: `replace '"cattle.io/timestamp":"[0-9T:Z-]*"','"cattle.io/timestamp":"(date -uformat +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")'` using single quotes to escape but apparently not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
$s = '"cattle.io/timestamp":"2022-02-22T11:11:00Z"'
$s -replace '("cattle\.io/timestamp":")[\dTZ:-]*(")',"`${1}$(date -uformat +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")`$2"
```

In your code:

```
$command = (curl --silent -H "Authorization: Bearer token-xxx" --url 'link.com' -X GET  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' --insecure 2>&1) -replace '("cattle\.io/timestamp":")[\dTZ:-]*(")',"`${1}$(date -uformat +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")`$2"
```

Output:

```
"cattle.io/timestamp":"2022-02-23T11:07:56Z"
```

*Details*:

- `-replace` is the operator that supports regex based search and replace in Powershell
- `("cattle\.io/timestamp":")` - Capturing group 1 (`$1`) that matches a literal `"cattle.io/timestamp":"` text (note the literal dot needs to be escaped in regular expressions)
- `[\dTZ:-]*` - matches zero or more digits, `T`, `Z`, `:` or `-` chars
- `(")` - Capturing group 2 that matches a `"` char
- `` "`${1}$(date -uformat +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")`$2" `` is the replacement that represents a double quoted string literal (and hence allowing string interpolation), that replaces each match found with `-replace` with Group 1 value (see the `` "`${1}" `` numeric backreference to Group 1, the backtick before `$` tells Powershell this is not an interpolated variable, and the braces are necessary since the next char will be a numeric char) + date (it needs `$(...)` syntax) and then Group 2 value (you might just use a `` `" `` instead if you do not want to introduce another capturing group in the pattern).

Comment: Hm I wonder if i'm missing out on something then because this text im trying to find is from within a large json for example. `"annotations":{"cattle.io/timestamp":"2022-02-22T11:11:00Z"},` and of course that time can vary inside the json. I am using powershell 7 and if I try to do `$command = (curl --silent -H "Authorization: Bearer token-xxx" --url 'link.com' -X GET  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' --insecure 2>&1 | replace '("cattle\.io/timestamp":")[\dTZ:-]*(")',"`${1}$(date -uformat +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")`$2")`  then i get `Path not found`

Comment: Do not use a pipe, use `$command = (...) -replace 'pattern', 'replacement'`. Again, it is not `replace`, it is `-replace`.

Comment: Thank you! I hadn't realised that the reason -replace wasn't working because of the pipe